# inner join between 3 tables

Tags: php, join, mysqli, inner-join

i have these table in database:

```
country:

id      country
------------------
1       USA
2       Brazil
```

and segment table:

```
id      country
------------------
1       USA
2       Brazil
```

i have a third table:

`Id     segment_id     country_id`

where segment_id is a foreign key of id in segment table

and country_id is a foreign key of id in country table

myquestion is:

how to select from the other table with inner join of the 3 tables,

i need to show the name of the country plus for every country show all the segments in a dropdown menu if anyone could help me

thank u

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: yes but it not working so i need the solution please thank u @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: If you tried something, post it here so others can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

you just try this

```html
$sql = select * from third_table 
       inner join country on third_table.country_id = country.id
       inner join segment on third_table.segment_id = segment.id
$res = mysql_query($sql);

   'or'


   select * from TableA A 
   inner join TableB B on A.Column=B.Column 
   inner join TableC C on A.Column=C.Column
```

Comment: [Please neither recommend using nor use `mysql_*()` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/2298301). They've been deprecated long ago and aren't a part of the build in PHP 7.0 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM third_table t
INNER JOIN country c ON t.country_id = c.country_id
INNER JOIN segment s ON t.segment_id = s.segment_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query.. this will help you to create list

```
select countrysegments.id as countrysegmentsID, country.country as countryName,
segment.country as segmentName
from countrysegments 
       inner join country on countrysegments.country_id  = country.id
       inner join segment on countrysegments.segment_id = segment.id
```